# CreateProcess Fails - Error 183

Tags: c++, windows, createprocess

So, code I can't change calls an executable, and I need to give it different commandline args than what the black box code calls. I was figuring I could make an executable to serve as a proxy. `proc.exe` sits where the black box section is expecting, takes the commandline arguments, modifies them, then calls `procReal.exe`, the original file.

Unfortunately CreateProcess seems to fail to start, returning status 183. I've looked up everything I can and can't find out much about this. Have tried flipping things around, setting the handle inheritance to true, manually specifying the working directory, not doing either of those things. No luck. I assume there's something going on here with inheriting the proper security context of the calling application so the wrapper works as a proper passthrough, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Code below, irrelevant sections pruned.

**EDIT** Put the full code here after request. This isn't making any sense anymore. It now will partially work, but only if the `fopen` section for `traceFile` isn't there. Not even the fprintfs removed, specifically the whole section has to be cut out.

I've tried to respond to everyone's comments and I think I've ruled out most of those things as an issue, but am left with the current anomalous behavior. What little more I could read up on this says that some forms of copying the strings around could lead to memory overflows, is that possible at all?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool caseInsensitiveStringCompare( const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2 );

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    const string path = "E:\\util\\bin\\";
    const string procName = "procReal.exe";
    const string argToFilter = "-t";


    string origValue;
    string passedValue;

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        origValue.append(" ").append(argv[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (!caseInsensitiveStringCompare(argv[i],argToFilter))
        {
            passedValue.append(" ").append(argv[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            i++; // skip over argument and it's value
        }

    }

    const LPCTSTR exeModule = (path+procName).c_str();

    std::vector<char> chars(passedValue.c_str(), passedValue.c_str() + passedValue.size() + 1u);
    LPTSTR exeArgs = &chars[0];


    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    GetStartupInfo(&si);

    FILE* traceFile;
  traceFile = fopen ((path+"lastRun.txt").c_str(), "w");  // This causes exeModule to change value for unknown reasons???
  fprintf(traceFile, "orig: %s%s\n", exeModule, origValue.c_str());
  fprintf(traceFile, "%s%s\n", exeModule, exeArgs);

  SetLastError(0);

    // Start the child process.
    if( !CreateProcess( exeModule,   // use module name with args for exeArgs
        exeArgs,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        TRUE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL, // use parent's starting directory
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    )
    {
        FILE* myfile;
        myfile = fopen ((path+"error.txt").c_str(), "w");
        fprintf(myfile, "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", int(GetLastError()));
        fclose(myfile);
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject( pi.hProcess, INFINITE );

    DWORD exit_code;
    GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exit_code);

    fprintf(traceFile, "Exit Code: %d\n", int(exit_code));
    fclose(traceFile);

    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    return exit_code;
}

bool caseInsensitiveStringCompare( const std::string& str1, const std::string& str2 ) {
    std::string str1Cpy( str1 );
    std::string str2Cpy( str2 );
    std::transform( str1Cpy.begin(), str1Cpy.end(), str1Cpy.begin(), ::tolower );
    std::transform( str2Cpy.begin(), str2Cpy.end(), str2Cpy.begin(), ::tolower );
    return ( str1Cpy == str2Cpy );
}
```

Comment: error code 183 means "ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS"

Comment: Is UAC enabled on your computer? Does procReal.exe need administrator privileges? Does proc.exe have them? Did you try running it with UAC disabled?

Comment: The base proc can be run directly without an administrator privileges, yea.

Comment: Is another instance of procReal running? Maybe it uses some objects with exclusive access.

Comment: Nope. I've debugged this to hell, and can't get it. I've checked permissions, I've watched it get opened in ProcMon and looked for any irregularities. It only opens one at a time, with seemingly nothing special about it.

Comment: How do you normally start procReal.exe? I mean do you double click it in Windows Explorer or is it added to the Run key in Registry?

Comment: Firefox add-on calls it. Which was weird in the first place so that might be the aspect of things being missed here. But I mean. I should really hope that a webbrowser isn't running with elevated permissions... It can call the original executable fine enough

Comment: Do you get the same error if you SetLastError(0); before the CreateProces call?

Comment: Please post the debugging code.  It is likely that you aren't retrieving the error code properly.  Also, `exeArgs` should be a char buffer, not a pointer to a constant string, and it should look like `procReal -args` not just `-args`.

Comment: The code is too obfuscated to see the core problem.  Crystal ball says that the *real* value of `exeModule` contains a space.  Put extra "double-quotes" around the path.

Comment: Yes, your error handling code is wrong.  You MUST call GetLastError BEFORE doing anything else, e.g., calling fopen().  That's why you aren't getting an error code that corresponds to the real problem - the "file already exists" code is coming from the fact that fopen() is opening an existing file.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that you are building the C strings improperly. Most obviously, you can't say `(path+procName).c_str()` because the temporary string object it builds is discarded immediately, invalidating the returned pointer.  (Also, I suspect that converting a `vector` into an array by taking a pointer to the first object is improper.)

Comment: ... for completeness, you've also overlooked that the first element of `exeArgs` has to be a module name.  You can fix this by initializing `passedValue` to be equal to `procName` rather than starting out with an empty string.  (A more subtle problem is that this approach will result in the command line arguments being double-parsed, which may break command lines containing special characters such as quote marks and backslashes.  Ideally, you would be calling GetCommandLine() and modifying that string rather than depending on argv[].)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious problem is that you can't say `(path+procName).c_str()` because the temporary string object it builds is discarded immediately, invalidating the returned pointer.  <strike>I'm also very dubious about assuming that the elements of a `vector` are necessarily consecutive.</strike>

The corrected string handling code should look something like this:

```
    string passedValue(procName);  // First element of command line MUST be module name

    ...

    const string exeModuleString(path + procName);
    const LPCTSTR exeModule = exeModuleString.c_str();

    LPTSTR exeArgs = new char[passedValue.size() + 1];
    passedValue.copy(exeArgs, passedValue.size());
    exeArgs[passedValue.size()] = '\0';
```

(That might not be *the* best way to do it; I don't use C++ often.  But it should work correctly.)

The corrected error handling code, ensuring that the last error code is read *immediately*, should look something like this:

```
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        FILE* myfile;
        myfile = fopen ((path+"error.txt").c_str(), "w");
        fprintf(myfile, "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", int(err));
        fclose(myfile);
    }
```

Your code was reporting the wrong error code, because calling fopen() changes it.  (When a new file is created that overwrites an existing file, the last error code is set to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`.)

There are two broader issues, which may or may not matter in your context.  Firstly, you're using argv[] to build the command line for the new process; that means that the command line parsing (as described in [Parsing C Command-Line Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1y7w461.aspx)) will be applied twice (once by your process and once by the child) which may cause trouble if the command line contains any special characters such as quote marks or backslashes.  Ideally, in the general case, you would call GetCommandLine() instead.  (Granted, this makes parsing the string to remove the extra argument quite a bit harder.)

Secondly, you're obviously building the code in ANSI mode.  This may cause problems if the command line ever contains any wide ("Unicode") characters.  It is generally accepted that best practice is to always build in Unicode mode.  The only major change you'll need to make to the code is to replace `string` with `wstring`, so it should be straightforward enough.

Comment: The elements of a vector are guaranteed to be consecutive, since C++11.

Comment: @Buster: thanks.  As I understand it, the latest version of Visual Studio is *mostly* C++11 compliant, so that part of the original code was probably OK.

Comment: This has sorted out either all or most of my problems, especially the GetCommandLine() part, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. 
The problem seems to be there when i call executables with no window.
I found 2 solutions:

1.
Create a bat file with the name of thet exe, followed by the arguments, 
and then execute the bat file:
CreateProcess( "temp.bat" , NULL , ....etc

2.
use _spawnl